# Adblock. Add css class or remove attribute from element

Tags: adblock

Is it possible to add css rule to an element at some page by adblock? 
Something like this

```
#myElement {
    color: white !important;
}
```

I tried to find a script that updates style of this element on page load but it seems that it is not a best way.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's possible to do it on uBlock Origin and Adguard (as far as I know). Each has its own syntax for the styling rules, but uBlock is capable understanding both.

---

Here is an example of a CSS rule that changes Twitter background:

```
twitter.com#$#body.logged-in{ background-color: #8c8787 !important; }
```

The styling filters should be constructed like this:

```
<domain> + #$# + <selector> + { <style> }
```

Just avoid puting a space between the selector and the opening brace. Cause it can give you some trouble. Reference:

https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#style
https://adguard.com/en/filterrules.html#cosmetic-css-rules

Answer (score 17):

The other answers weren't working for me but there is a way to change an element's style:

```
example.com##h1:style(background-color: blue !important)
```

Make sure not to use curly brackets.

There is also some documentation on  [GitHub](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#style).

EDIT: As BeeLabeille mentioned this advice seems specific to uBlock.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that, similar to the other answers, your solution also applies to ublock and not adblock as specified in the question

Comment: Can confirm, this is the only solution that worked for adblock (Sept 2022)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible for AdBlock to change CSS properties, you can use an extension like [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/help/stylish) (available for Firefox and Chrome) to do just that though.

Answer (score -2):

For AdBlock Plus, you can try this:

```
##.ytp-pause-overlay, .ytp-scroll-min
##.html5-endscreen, .ytp-player-content, .videowall-endscreen, .ytp-endscreen-paginate, .ytp-show-tiles
##.ytp-endscreen-content
```

This should disable the display of ads during the pause, and recommended videos, at the end of the video.

PS: Ah.. this is not the subject of the question.. this removes the class from the div element. Well, maybe someone will come in handy, to delete unnecessary blocks in the Youtube player.